# How to show a notification button in title bar (or a general button if not possible)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I would like to add a button to the title bar of my C++/Qt application, like the one for Visual Studio notifications (I've seen other programs using it too, like SourceTree).

[image]

I have been searching around for a while but many pages redirect to [this](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/titlebar.asp) or [this](https://www.codeproject.com/vb/net/transmenuandtitlebuttons.aspx) broken links. I've only found [this CodeProject tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7287/CCaptionButton-buttons-for-the-titlebar) but my whole project is powered by Qt, not MFC.

Is there any standard/native way to do it using Qt or in C++?

PS: third-party window decoration replacements looks promising, but I would like not to make such replacement on standard Windows frame.

Comment: You can do this by removing the title bar and putting buttons yourself there.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, thanks, I've tried that before for other kind of requirements and I've ended up with too much manual overwriting of standard behaviors: window moving/sizing/snapping, global shortcut for minimizing... it is an option but I'd prefer a "less invasive" one ;)

Comment: It is not possible with Qt alone. You will have to use native stuff to add it there or use a custom titlebar. There are already projects like [this one](https://github.com/deimos1877/BorderlessWindow) that handle all the borderless stuff, including snapping etc. You can use those and extend them to add your buttons

Comment: Or maybe QML does this?

Comment: @Felix thanks! it seems such project can work, definitely I'll take a look at it

Comment: @cbuchart: I made my own implementation of a border less window called `QGoodWindow`, it's goal is to be simple to implement and Qt 5 friendly, no native code required from you and you can port your code to where the border less window are unavailable like Linux and Android. [See here](https://github.com/antonypro/QGoodWindow)!